# Push_back doesn't work

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

Tried on Visual 2010, Visual 2012 and CodeBlocks without success. I've been roaming the internet for an answer for the past 3 days and have found nothing to help me.

I've tried two ways, first

```
    vector<int> mvec;
    int num;
    while(cin >> num)
       mvec.push_back(num);
    cout << mvec[0];
```

Should output the first number of any input. Instead it does nothing. It does print the first number if I input a letter either after inputting a sequence of numbers or behind it.

Tried this too

```
    vector<int> myvector;
    int myint;

    do {
      cin >> myint;
      myvector.push_back(myint);
    } while (myint);

    cout << myvector[0];
```

Again, nothing. I found this last snippet while googling and it obviously worked for it's creator.

Some online compilers tell me the output for 1 3 4 for example is 1. One I found says the program is trying to print an empty vector

At the very least could someone try to run either of these and tell me whether or not they work? I'll include a full program below.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    int main()
    {
        using namespace std;
        vector<int> mvec;
        int num = 0;
        while(cin >> num)
            mvec.push_back(num);
        cout << mvec[0];
    }
```

Thank you for your time and apologies if this is very obvious.

Comment: The issue you're having is that the loop never exits. That's a design decision you need to make. How do you know when the user has finished entering input? Come up with that answer and then it should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 4):

If you enter values

```
1 2 3 4
```

You need to end with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> in Unix) which is eof in order to stop input.

The code works fine by me (VS2012)

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> mvec;
int num;
while(cin >> num)
   mvec.push_back(num);
cout << mvec[0];
```

The loop will continue so long as cin >> num was successful. In other words, only by entering a non-number will the loop end and then print out the first number.

```
vector<int> myvector;
int myint;

do {
  cin >> myint;
  myvector.push_back(myint);
} while (myint);

cout << myvector[0];
```

When using an integer where a bool is expected, a value of 0 becomes false and any other value becomes true. This loop will only stop when a 0 is entered, as this causes myint to become false.

I am not sure what exactly you want to do. If you only want to enter one number, don't use a loop (and a vector is not required) If you want to enter a certain number of numbers, you will need a for loop which executes a set number of times.

```
int num;
cout << "How many numbers do you want to enter?" << endl;
if (! (cin >> num))
{
    cout << "Error expected a number" << endl;
    return -1;
}

vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    int x;
    if (! (cin >> x))
        {
        cout << "Error expected a number" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    vec.push_back(x);
}

for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "number entered: " << vec[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to enter a 0 eventually to break out of the loop. So 1 3 4 0 would result in 1. But you can never put a 0 in the vector using this method. The vector will only have [1, 3, 4] in it.

Comment: This applies to the second code snippet in the question (the one with `do` ... `while (myint)`)

Answer (score 0):

First things first - there's nothing wrong with `push_back`. :)

How are you expecting to terminate the `while( cin >> num )` loop? It looks like you're using Windows, so `<Ctrl-Z>` would cause `cin` to become invalid, and so terminate the while-loop. On Un*x like systems, it's `<Ctrl-D>`.

The reason entering a letter terminates the loop is that `cin` is attempting to put the result in a numerical variable, and can't parse the string to a number.

Your program works for me.

(NB: entering `0` will not terminate the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Bjarne Stroustrup has an example of an std::vector and push_back on his website:

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#simple-program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> v;

    double d;
    while(cin>>d) v.push_back(d);   // read elements
    if (!cin.eof()) {       // check if input failed
        cin.clear();        // clear error state
        string s;
        cin >> s;       // look for terminator string
        if (s != "end") {
            cerr << "format error\n";
            return 1;   // error return
        }
    }

    cout << "read " << v.size() << " elements\n";

    reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
    cout << "elements in reverse order:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i<v.size(); ++i) cout << v[i] << '\n';

    return 0; // success return
}
```

You just type in your numbers separated by spaces and when you are done type **end**

It's good for beginners because it doesn't rely on the variable end-of-file characters of different operating systems.

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible that your standard output buffer isn't flushing.  Try this:

```
cout << myVec[0] << flush;
```

Or this:

```
cout << myVec[0] << endl;
```

Comment: `std::cout` will be flushed when he returns from `main`.